# Self-leveling concrete prep: how to fill large gaps?

Tags: subfloor, self-leveling-concrete

[Note: Variations of this question have been asked before, but the ones that received answers were talking about sealing gaps for other purposes. So here goes.]

TL;DR: I have 3/4”-1” gaps at the edges of my floor. What material do I use to fill those?

In preparation for laying Marmoleum click tiles (like LVT, but ecologically friendlier), I’m leveling my kitchen floor.

There is a joist that runs through the center of the kitchen under the floor which creates a slight ridge. It’s a 1/2” height difference to the back door and a 1/4” difference to the wall opposite the back door.

The most recent flooring choice made by the person who sold me the house was 13” ceramic tile over concrete backer board.

Due to the flexible nature of a 1900 wood frame house in a seismic zone, over 50% of the tiles cracked over the span of 10 years.

I pulled all of that material out earlier in the project.

The pre-existing floor is glue-down vinyl tiles over a hardboard substrate. It’s tested negative for asbestos, one of the few breaks I’ve caught in this project, but due to complications I won’t go into, cutting out the high part isn’t feasible.

So my plan is:

1. Where possible, use plywood in the low spots to raise the floor level at the edges, being mindful that I can’t just slap a 1/4” sheet down - because that just maintains the slope while adding 1/4” of height to it, moving the ridge rather than removing it
2. Seal all edges, screw holes from the concrete backer board, and seams with a combination of caulk, Tyvek house wrap tape, and sill seal.
3. Prime all flooring surfaces with the primer required to use Levelquik RS Self-Leveling compound.
4. Add metal lath where possible to add structure and strength to the concrete (it’s likely this will only be possible at the back door since that has the greatest height delta).
5. Create dams at the door thresholds to prevent unintended spread.
6. Use self-leveling compound to fill the remaining sloped gaps

In several places along the walls, there are large gaps that are too big to fill with just caulk, but too small to reasonably fill with plywood. These are not high-traffic areas, where the gaps are. What material should I use? I’m considering:

- roofing paper, folded up into multiple layers
- Spray foam, which can be trimmed down later

Any advice you can give would be most appreciated. I hope this makes sense; I typed it on my phone.

Pix:
Wall 1:
[image: wall 1]

Wall 2:
[image: wall 2]

Comment: Spray foam at a guess, but let someone who's tried the options weigh in with an answer.

Comment: Enlarge the gap by cutting off a slice of the existing sub-base, then fit the larger gaps.

Comment: "Backer rod" is usually used when you're caulking and need to fill a large gap. It's basically a stiff foam rod, available in several diameters. In this case, fill the gap with backer rod, then caulk over that for sealing, then apply the SLC. This is a comment, because I've never tried it, but it's a thought that came to mind.

Comment: @FreeMan thank you, I suspected there was a product like this. Gonna head down to Home Depot and give them yet more of my money.